# Query function Google Sheet - Aggregation + (unwanted) Sorting

Tags: sql, google-sheets

I am trying to run what it started as a simple task but it turned out to be more complicated.

I must run a local sum of a column over different elements of another column with a query function.
The issue arises because the query performs an unwanted sorting of the grouped column (it is in the format of working weeks - strings) and I cannot get it to unsort or re-sort in the original format.

Initial query is:

```
=query(A1:B350,"select A, sum(B) group by A")
```

See the example:
[click here to see example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BjTY6.png)

Subsequently I tried with:

```
=query(A1:B350,"select A, sum(B) where A matches '"&join("|", query(G2:G, "select G where G is not null"))& "' group by A")
```

like so:
[click here to see example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5Kgo2.png)

but the unwanted sorting remains.

Any idea on how to force the initial sorting or preventing it from changing?
Thank you in advance

Comment: share a copy of your sheet

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To sort correctly, you need to align single digits. You can do this either in the source data or using a formula:

```
=QUERY({INDEX(REGEXREPLACE(A:A,"-(\d)$","-0$1")),B:B},"SELECT Col1, SUM(Col2) GROUP BY Col1")
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
=INDEX(IFNA(VLOOKUP(G2:G, 
 QUERY(A1:B350, "select A,sum(B) group by A label sum(B)''"), {1, 2}, 0)))
```

Comment: Hi, it doesn't seem to work. It only outputs from 2021-13 onward - from 2021-3 to 2021-12 are not printed out and empty cells are there.

Comment: @Lore456 can you share a copy of your sheet?